# UEFI misconfiguration after Ubuntu 64 bit installation SSD slot disabled

Tags: nvidia, uefi, ssd, firmware

The Hwinfo64 report delivers the following results for my HP Pavilion:

1. in the motherboard section

Motherboard Slots:  2xPCI Express x1, 1xPCI Express x8, 1xPCI Express x16

1. in the bus section

PCI Express x8 Bus #1 [J6B2]
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti [HP]
[General Information]
Device Name:    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti [HP]
Original Device Name:   NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (GP107M)
Device Class:   VGA Compatible Adapter
Revision ID:    A1
PCI Address (Bus: Device:
Function) Number:   1:0:0
PCI Latency Timer:  0
Hardware ID:    PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8C&SUBSYS_84ED103C&REV_A1
[PCI Express]
Version:    3.0
Maximum Link Width: 16x
Current Link Width: 8x
Maximum Link Speed: 8.0 GT/s
Current Link Speed: 2.5 GT/s
Device/Port Type:   PCI Express Endpoint
Slot Implemented:   No
Emergency Power Reduction:  Not Supported
Active State Power Management (ASPM) Support:   L0s and L1
Active State Power Management (ASPM) Status:    L0s and L1 Entry
L0s Exit Latency:   256 - 512 ns
L1 Exit Latency:    2 - 4 us
Maximum Payload Size Supported: 256 bytes
Maximum Payload Size:   256 bytes
Resizable BAR Support:  Not Supported
[System Resources]
Interrupt Line: N/A
Interrupt Pin:  INTA#
Memory Base Address 0   63000000
Memory Base Address 1   50000000
Memory Base Address 3   60000000
I/O Base Address 5  0
[Features]
Bus Mastering:  Enabled
Running At 66 MHz:  Not Capable
Fast Back-to-Back Transactions: Not Capable
[Driver Information]
Driver Manufacturer:    NVIDIA
Driver Description: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Driver Provider:    NVIDIA
Driver Version: 27.21.14.6627 (GeForce 466.27)
Driver Date:    23-Apr-2021
DCH/UWD Driver: Capable
DeviceInstanceId    PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8C&SUBSYS_84ED103C&REV_A1\4&33ECA368&0&0008
Location Paths  PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0100)#PCI(0000)

The PCI Express bus enumeration ends with #3 and the NVMe PCIe SSD controller is not listed.

However, a Hwinfo64 report of a comparable board can be found on the Internet.

There, an NVMe PCIe SSD controller is listed in the Bus section (see below) under PCI Express x4.

PCI Express x4 Bus #4
Samsung NVMe PCIe SSD Controller

[General Information]
Device Name:    Samsung NVMe PCIe SSD Controller
Original Device Name:   Samsung Electronics NVMe PCIe SSD Controller
Device Class:   NVMe Controller
Revision ID:    0
PCI Address (Bus: Device: Function) Number: 4:0:0
PCI Latency Timer:  0
Hardware ID:    PCI\VEN_144D&DEV_A808&SUBSYS_A801144D&REV_00
[PCI Express]
Version:    3.0
Maximum Link Width: 4x
Current Link Width: 4x
Maximum Link Speed: 8.0 GT/s
Current Link Speed: 8.0 GT/s
Device/Port Type:   PCI Express Endpoint
Slot Implemented:   No
Emergency Power Reduction:  Not Supported
Active State Power Management (ASPM) Support:   L1
Active State Power Management (ASPM) Status:    L1 Entry
L0s Exit Latency:   >4 us
L1 Exit Latency:    32 - 64 us
Maximum Payload Size Supported: 256 bytes
Maximum Payload Size:   256 bytes
[System Resources]
Interrupt Line: N/A
Interrupt Pin:  INTA#
Memory Base Address 0   AD200000
[Features]
Bus Mastering:  Enabled
Running At 66 MHz:  Not Capable
Fast Back-to-Back Transactions: Not Capable
[Driver Information]
Driver Manufacturer:    Standard NVM Express Controller
Driver Description: Standard NVM Express Controller
Driver Provider:    Microsoft
Driver Version: 10.0.19041.488
Driver Date:    21-Jun-2006
DeviceInstanceId    PCI\VEN_144D&DEV_A808&SUBSYS_A801144D&REV_00\4&CDF9F35&0&00DC
Location Paths  PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1B04)#PCI(0000)

My HP Pavilion, on the other hand, does not have a PCI Express x4 slot, but it does have a PCI Express x8 slot. According to the Hwinfo64 report of my HP Pavilion notebook, the graphics card NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (GP107M) sits in the PCI Express x8 slot. Specified for this graphics card is: x4.

Maximum Link Width: 16x

In the Hwinfo64 report of the board used for comparison, the graphics card is attached to the PCI Express x16 bus #1 (see below) as listed in the Bus section, i.e. in the correct place (16 lanes).

PCI Express x16 Bus #1
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 [GIGABYTE]

[General Information]
Device Name:    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 [GIGABYTE]
Original Device Name:   NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 (GP106M/N17P-G1)
Device Class:   VGA Compatible Adapter
Revision ID:    A1
PCI Address (Bus:Device:Function) Number:   1:0:0
PCI Latency Timer:  0
Hardware ID:    PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C20&SUBSYS_16521458&REV_A1

Version:    3.0
Maximum Link Width: 16x
Current Link Width: 16x
Maximum Link Speed: 8.0 GT/s
Current Link Speed: 2.5 GT/s
Device/Port Type:   PCI Express Endpoint
Slot Implemented:   No
Emergency Power Reduction:  Not Supported
Active State Power Management (ASPM) Support:   L0s and L1
Active State Power Management (ASPM) Status:    L0s and L1 Entry
L0s Exit Latency:   256 - 512 ns
L1 Exit Latency:    8 - 16 us
Maximum Payload Size Supported: 256 bytes
Maximum Payload Size:   256 bytes

[System Resources]
Interrupt Line: N/A
Interrupt Pin:  INTA#
Memory Base Address 0   AC000000
Memory Base Address 1   80000000
Memory Base Address 3   90000000
I/O Base Address 5  0

[Features]
Bus Mastering:  Enabled
Running At 66 MHz:  Not Capable
Fast Back-to-Back Transactions: Not Capable

[Driver Information]
Driver Manufacturer:    NVIDIA
Driver Description: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060
Driver Provider:    NVIDIA
Driver Version: 27.21.14.5167 (GeForce 451.67)
Driver Date:    05-Jul-2020
DCH/UWD Driver: Capable
DeviceInstanceId    PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C20&SUBSYS_16521458&REV_A1\4&DAED9F9&0&0008
Location Paths  PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0100)#PCI(0000)

In the System Buses section of the SiSoft Sandra report of my Pavilion notebook (see below), there is a warning 1204 at the end. Possibly, the reference there to the higher maximum supported speed is due to the lower number of lanes (8 in the bus instead of 16).

SiSoftware Sandra Systembusse
Systembusse
Schnittstellenversion: 2.30
PCI Busse: 4
PCIe Busse: 3
Systembus
Typ: PCI
Gerätenummer: 0
Multiplikator: 1x
Systembus
Typ: PCIe 3.0 x8 2.5Gbps
Gerätenummer: 1
Multiplikator: 3x
Bridge: Intel Core6 (Skylake) PCIe Controller (x16)
Systembus
Typ: PCIe 3.0 x1 2.5Gbps
Gerätenummer: 2
Multiplikator: 3x
Bridge: Intel ICH300 (Cannon Point) PCI Express Root Port #14
Gerät mit Anschluss verbunden: HP RTL8168/8111 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC
Systembus
Typ: PCIe 3.0 x1 2.5Gbps
Gerätenummer: 3
Multiplikator: 3x
Bridge: Intel ICH300 (Cannon Point) PCI Express Root Port #16
Gerät mit Anschluss verbunden: HP RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
Leistungstipps
Warning 1204: Speed is below the maximum supported speed. The device may be in power-saving mode.
Tip 3: Press Enter or double-click on a tip to find out more information.

If there is a possibility to disconnect the NVIDIA graphics card electrically, I could unscrew the notebook, do the disconnection and boot the Windows partition (In the default setting, another graphics card is active, after all). The hardware initialization should then assign the NVMe SSD to the correct port, since the NVIDIA graphics card is no longer present.

What could be the reason that the PCI Express x16 Bus is not listed by HWINFO in the BUS section of the HP notebook and why the NVIDIA Graphics card is assigned to the PCI Express x8 Bus of the HP notebook instead of the PCI Express x16 Bus?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: I have a dual boot configuration. Windows 10 Home x64 up to date and Lubutu x64 up to date.

Comment: Machine is HP Pavilion - 17-ab403ng

Comment: Please provide release details.

Comment: Question is: Could Ubuntu have destroyed so parts of the hardware are inaccessible (see information in the first post)?

Comment: Please refer https://www.heise.de/ct/ausgabe/2013-6-UEFI-Funktionen-schuld-an-Notebook-Defekten-2326650.html

Comment: *Could Ubuntu have destroyed so parts of the hardware are inaccessible (see information in the first post)?* NO. And please do not post articles behind a paywall and especially not FUD